# Which is costlier - DB call or new call?

Tags: c++, database, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am debugging a process core dump and I would like to do a design change.
The C++ process uses eSQL/C to connect to the informix database.

Presently, the application uses a query which fetches more than 2lacs rows from the database. For each row, it creates dynamic memory using `new` and processes the result. It results in `Out of memory` errors at times, maybe because of inherent memory leaks.

I am thinking of an option by which I will query only 500 rows from the database at a time, allocate dynamic memory and process it. Once it is de-allocated, then load next 500 and so on.  But this would increase the number of DB queries, even though the dynamic memory required at a time is reduced.

So my question is whether this option is a scalable solution.
Whether more DB calls will make the application less scalable?

Comment: So you want to "hide" the "inherent memory leaks" by changing your queries??? Fix the problem, don't hide it...

Comment: identify if you have memory leaks or not and fix them if you do. Memory leaks do not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the query.

Your single call at the moment takes a certain amount of time to return all 200k rows. Let's say that time is proportional to the number of rows in the DB, call it `n`.

If it turns out that your new, smaller call *still* takes time proportional to the number of rows in the DB, then your overall operation will take time proportional to `n^2` (because you have to make `n / 500` calls at cost `n` each). This might not be scalable.

So, you need to make sure you have the right indexes in place in the database (or more likely, make sure that you divide up the rows into groups of 500 according to the order of some field that is indexed already) so that the smaller calls take time roughly proportional to the number of rows returned, rather than the number of rows in the DB. Then it might be scalable.

Anyway, if you do have memory leaks then they are bugs, they're not "inherent" and they should be removed!

Comment: It is a simple query based on the index.

Answer (score 0):

DB calls surely costs more that dynamic memory allocation(though both expensive). If you can't fix memory leaks, you should try this solution and tune number of rows to fetch for max efficency.

Anyway, memory leaks are huge problem and your solution will be just temporary. You should give a try to smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Holding all the records in memory while processing is not a very scalable unless you are processing a small number of records. Given that the current solution already fails, paging will definitely result in better scalability. While multiple round-trips will result in greater delays due to network latency, paging will allow you to work with a much larger number of records.

That said, you should definitely solve the memory leak errors, because you will still end up with out-of-memory exceptions, it will simply take longer for the leaks to accumulate to the point where the exception occurs.

Additionally, you should ensure that you do not keep any cursors open while paging, otherwise you may cause blocking problems for others. You should create a SQL statement that returns only one page of data at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly identify if you have memory leaks or not and fix them if you do.

Memory leaks do not scale well.

Secondly allocating dynamic memory is usually much faster than DB access - except when you are allocating a lot of memory and requiring increase in the heap.

If you are requesting a lot (100k upwards of rows) to perform processing - firstly ask yourself **why it is necessary to fetch all of these** - can the SQL be modified to perform the processing based on criteria - if you clarify the processing we can provide better advice about how to do this.

Fetching and processing large amounts of data need proper thought to ensure that it scales well.